# How to make an Image appear slowly on hover

Tags: hover

I have a cart on my website, I have maked a kind of graphic as image, that appear as bacground behind the cart when :hover.

But I was wondering how I can make this object fade/appear slowly on :hover, instead of instant as it is now.

I tried to copy the html and css from my website, but it looks bad in jsfiddle.
http://oliver.kaspertoxvig.dk/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the preferred way of doing it, but if you are using the jQuery library, this should do the trick:

```
$(function () {
  $(".cart-css-class").hover(
  function () {
    // Fade in on hover
    $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": "1" }, "slow");
  },
  function () {
   // Fade out when no longer hover
   $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": "0" }, "slow");
  });
});
```

This assumes your element has the css class cart-css-class. To hide it on load, you should apply this CSS:

```
.cart-css-class {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hej Henrik

Can you tell me how to use this when im using Wordpress? Can I add it to functions.php?

Comment: I have never used WordPress myself, so unfortunately I cannot help you with that.However, I think that functions.php might be for server-side functions only, and probably does not have any direct influence on the user interface. You should probably look for a way to add scripts and CSS to your theme.

Comment: Okay... I had hoped for a solution using CSS3.